# Tags: grammatical-case versus case

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When I was tagging one of my posts about case in time expressions I realized that when you try to tag a post with case, you have to choose between `grammatical-case` and just `case`. The former has 35 questions this year and the latter only 2. Is there a difference between the two I'm missing or is it just a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Good you brought that up. Both tags are already [synonymized](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) to [grammatical-case](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-case) being the "master" tag of its synonym [cases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases).

This also is why you had the choice for [grammatical-case](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-case) whenever you tag a question with [cases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases).

I merged these tags now so that [cases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases) will be replaced by [grammatical-case](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-case) from all questions.

Comment: How about "grammatical case" and "use case"("can I use this expression in the following scenario?")

I know use-case is a term from software-dev, but it would help eliminating ambiguity.